# General tableView questions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a little trouble understanding how multiple segue between multiple view controllers (specifically multiple table views) on a general level. Even after looking at responses and trying to search for examples of table views connecting to different table views, I still couldn't find a solid explanation and was wondering if someone could clarify for me. I'm not entirely sure of the whole logic and vertability of what is legal or illegal, so please take my two scenarios with a grain of salt and let me know if I got some assumptions wrong!

[image: TableViewExample]

I have two potential scenarios trying to achieve different table view cells for each row in the "Table View Controller" - examples of different cells is highlighted in the box in blue on the right.

The first scenario, I was thinking was to make three different types of prototype cell and depending on whether I can check which indexPath the "Table View Controller" was selected, I can create the appropriate cell to make from the "List of Subs View Controller" by using the cell identifiers.

The second, I was planning to make three different and seperate view controllers depicted in the image by "View Controller #1 / #2 / #3" and create one prototype cell that is appropriate to each row. I'm little hesistant about this approach considering that the cells in "Main View Controller" is all the same and it seems a bit redundant to create seperate view controllers. This way, I could tell what each "List of Subs View Controller" cells type would be simply by the segue identifier.

If Scenario #1 is correct, how would I get the cell identifier from the "Table View Controller" when I'm currently viewing "List of Subs View Controller" in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, both scenarios would work.

> If Scenario #1 is correct, how would I get the cell identifier from the "Table View Controller" when I'm currently viewing "List of Subs View Controller" in Swift?

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ...
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    let reuseIdentifier = cell.reuseIdentfier
    ...
}
```

(Beware, optional handling is not optimal in the code above, I leave this to you)

On the other hand, I am not sure that using the reuseIdnetifier in that way is the best thing to do.

I would represent the cell type in your model, then use that information to decide what to segue to.